# Android WebView won't load a javascript graph

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webpage that shows a graph. It uses javascript, jquery, bootstrap and angular.js. In my android app I try to load this graph using a WebView. This is the code in the android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview_webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(getArguments().getString(MY_URL));
```

When I start the fragment, this is the log I get:

```
10-30 13:09:57.655: W/art(31893): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
10-30 13:09:57.659: W/AwContents(31893): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
10-30 13:09:57.796: W/cr.BindingManager(31893): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 31893
10-30 13:09:58.052: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/modernizr.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.055: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.057: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.060: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.niftymodals/js/jquery.modalEffects.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.062: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/masonry.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.065: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.nanoscroller/jquery.nanoscroller.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.068: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.ui/jquery-ui.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.072: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.074: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.077: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.nestable/jquery.nestable.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.082: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap.switch/bootstrap-switch.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.093: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap.datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.096: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap.clockpicker/js/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.101: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.icheck/icheck.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.104: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.select2/select2.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.107: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.parsley/parsley.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.109: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/skycons/skycons.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.119: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap.slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.119: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/intro.js/intro.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.119: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.121: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.crop/dist/cropper.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.123: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/datepicker/js/jquery-ui.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.126: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/angular.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.128: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/angular-ui-router.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.133: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/angular-animate.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.133: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/toaster.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.305: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/infobox.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.306: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/markerclusterer.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.307: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/highstock.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.308: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/exporting.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.310: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/ng-highcharts.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.311: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.312: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.315: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/behaviour/general.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.317: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/behaviour/voice-commands.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.319: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.321: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.323: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.pie.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.324: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.flot/jquery.flot.labels.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.326: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery.icheck/icheck.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.328: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.329: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.343: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/moment.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.345: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.custom.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.349: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.352: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.354: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/bootstrapValidator.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.355: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/jQuery-Storage-API/jquery.storageapi.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.357: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.358: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/fullcalendar/appcalendar.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.359: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/pt-br.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.361: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/gcal.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.362: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/LAB.min.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.365: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/aside/angular-aside.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.366: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//app/app/app.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.368: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//app/app/data.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.370: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//app/app/directives.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.371: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//app/app/controllers.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.373: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//app/app/modules.js (1)
10-30 13:09:58.374: I/chromium(31893): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: mydomain//js/sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js (1)
```

As you can see, there is an "unexpected token <" error for each javascript file loaded in the page. I think this error maybe a mistake, because the page loads normally in any browser.

Have somebody seen this before? What can I try? Thanks.

Comment: Just because the page loads seemingly normally in browsers doesn't necessarily mean its HTML syntax is correct. Browsers always try their absolute best to render *something*, even if the HTML is wrong. Try running it through a validator or post the link here so we can check.

Comment: Tried to validate on "https://validator.w3.org/" and "html5.validator.nu", both went OK. Unfortunatelly, I can't post the link. What do you think about this error "unexpected token <" occurring in every included javascript file,@Michael? Maybe some bug in WebView or something like it?

Comment: Next thing I'd do is check that your server is sending the correct response headers on the JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was with file permissions in the server.